# Unable to get the desired overflow of div after using all the method suggested

Tags: html, css

I want my div alignment like shown in the image below....

[image]

But I am getting something like this.....

[image]

Only fixed positioning worked for me ... but I don't want to use that....

Here is my html code...

```
<div class="profileHeader">
    <span class="img" style="background: url(http://localhost/Amar/public/assets/images/temp/restaurant.jpeg) #B3E5FC center center / cover no-repeat;"></span>
    <span class="gradientBottom"></span>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="profilePicWrapper">
            <div class="profilePic">
                <img src="assets/images/temp/shop.jpg" alt="Alt here"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="optionWrapper"></div>
```

And here is my css code....

```
.profileHeader {
height: 400px;
position: relative;
}
.profileHeader .gradientBottom {
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50%;
position: absolute;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,color-stop(0,rgba(0,0,0,0)),color-stop(20%,rgba(0,0,0,.13)),color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,.5)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0) 20%,rgba(0,0,0,.5) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#a6000000', GradientType=0);
}
.profilePicWrapper {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
.profilePic {
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
border: 1px solid #999;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
margin-top: 200px;
}
.profilePic img {
width: 100%;
display: block;
}
.optionWrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background: #fff;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
border-bottom: 1px solid #414042;
}
```

I am unable to figure out what is going wrong... Please help...

Comment: Why don't you want to use fixed positioning?

Comment: my website is responsive and a lot of adjustment is required to deal with fixed positioning.....

Comment: I thought it would be something like that. Can you put the images up on [imgur](http://imgur.com) so I can use them in a fiddle?

Comment: ok wait... I m uploading..

Comment: Ok here is the link... http://imgur.com/a/18Stl

Comment: Hmmm... can't figure this out. If someone else doesn't answer it in a few days, I'll put a bounty on it.

Comment: I am quite new here .... Help me out if you can......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your original HTML (with one change, I pulled the inline CSS out) and removing all CSS not relevant to the positioning you're trying to achieve:

```css
.profileHeader{
  width: 570px; height: 210px; 
  position:relative;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/570x210') #B3E5FC center center / cover no-repeat;
}

.profilePic {
  border: 4px solid #FFF;
  position:absolute; 
  right: 50px; 
  bottom: -80px;
}

.optionWrapper {
  margin-right: 400px; /* leave room for profile pic */
  min-height: 80px; /* ensure profile pic doesn't overlap following content */
}
```

```html
<p>This is content before the element</p>
<div class="profileHeader">
    <span class="img" style=""></span>
    <span class="gradientBottom"></span>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="profilePicWrapper">
            <div class="profilePic">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/280x210" alt="Alt here"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="optionWrapper">This is the content of optionWrapper</div>
<p>This is content after the element</p>
```

Essentially, set the container to `position: relative` so that the absolute positioning of the child element `.profilePic` will be relative to its dimensions; then use a negative bottom margin on the child element to create the offset positioning.

This shouldn't affect the layout of the rest of the page the way that `position:fixed` would, since the absolute positioning is only set on the one element you want to float above the others.

Comment: Thanks for your effort sir, But  i my site is responsive and i need to display contents as navbar link on left of image...

Comment: This should work just fine with a responsive design (the profile pic will be positioned relative to the right/bottom of the container element regardless of the container's size.)  

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "i need to display contents as navbar link on left of image" -- which image? What content? Positioned how?  Please include that information in the question if you want it to be part of the answers.

Comment: On the left of which image -- profilePic or profileHeader? What should its positioning be relative to the rest?

Again: if you need something specific in the answers, *you need to include it in the question*. We can't read minds.

Comment: I have taken a guess at the positioning, since you seem unwilling to describe it, and included that in the answer.